# What is the difference between ref, toRef and toRefs?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I have just started working with Vue 3 and the Composition API.

What are the differences between `ref`, `toRef` and `toRefs`?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

#### Vue 3 `ref`

A [ref](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref) is a mechanism for reactivity in Vue 3.  The idea is to wrap a non-object variable inside a `reactive` object:

> Takes an inner value and returns a reactive and mutable ref object. The ref object has a single property `.value` that points to the inner value.

<sub>**Hmm.. Why?**</sub>

Vue 3 relies on JavaScript [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to detect changes to your reactive data and implement the reactivity.  Proxies are essentially event listeners for objects: any reading or writing on a proxied object triggers the proxy, which can then do something with the values.  This is convenient for reactivity since the variable changing will provide a trigger from which Vue can update any dependencies.

But proxies require objects to work.  So Vue provides the `ref` method to convert your non-object variables into objects and then to grant reactive capabilities through a proxy.  (Objects are [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Object_reference) variables, hence the name `ref`.)

<sup>(And Vue automatically unwraps your `refs` in the template, which is an added benefit of `ref` that you wouldn't get if you wrapped your value variables in an object manually.)</sup>

#### `reactive`

If your original variable is already an object (or array), a `ref` wrapping is not needed because it is already a *reference* type.  It only needs Vue's [reactive](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#reactive) functionality (which a `ref` also has):

```js
const state = reactive({
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
})
```

But now consider copying a property from the object above to a new variable, for example `foo` which contains the number `1`.  If you copied this to a new variable, the copy would of course be a regular, non-reactive variable having no connection to the reactive object it was copied from.  If `foo` changed later, the copy would not, meaning the copy is not reactive.  This is where `toRef` is useful.

#### `toRef`

[`toRef`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#toref) converts a single `reactive` object property to a `ref` that **maintains its connection with the parent object**:

> ```js
> const state = reactive({
>   foo: 1,
>   bar: 2
> })
>
> const fooRef = toRef(state, 'foo')
> /*
> fooRef: Ref<number>,
> */
> ```

Now if `state.foo` changes, `fooRef.value` will change as well.  So `toRef` has enabled copying a value property in such a way that the copy also has a reactive connection to the original parent object.

#### `toRefs`

[`toRefs`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#torefs) converts *all* of the object's properties, to a new plain object having properties that are refs:

> ```js
> const state = reactive({
>   foo: 1,
>   bar: 2
> })
>
> const stateAsRefs = toRefs(state)
> /*
> {
>   foo: Ref<number>,
>   bar: Ref<number>
> }
> */
> ```

**When would I ever use `toRef` or `toRefs`?**

The most likely time would be when importing a reactive object that has value properties like the example, such as from a composable, and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) it.  The act of destructuring will pull the current property value from the object into a new local variable that will not be reactive without `toRef`.  You may notice this when importing and destructuring a [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) store into your component, for example.

Comment: For toRef, the line "to a ref that maintains its connection with the parent object" was key for me. I was wondering why toRef exists since you can just do ```const fooRef = ref(state.foo)```, but that creates a disconnected ref; any changes to it only update fooRef's dependencies. But using toRef keeps the original connection.

Answer (score 22):

**reactive**

`reactive` creates a deeply reactive **proxy** **object** based on a given **object**. The proxy object will look exactly the same as the given, plain object, but any mutation, no matter how deep it is, will be reactive - this includes all kinds of mutations including property additions and deletions. The important thing is that `reactive` can only work with objects, not primitives.

For example, `const state = reactive({foo: {bar: 1}})` means:

- `state.foo` is reactive (it can be used in template, computed and watch)
- `state.foo.bar` is reactive
- `state.baz`, `state.foo.baz`, `state.foo.bar.baz` are also reactive even though `baz` does not yet exist anywhere. This might look surprising (especially when you start to dig how reactivity in vue works). By **`state.baz` being reactive**, I mean within your template/computed properties/watches, you can write `state.baz` literally and expect your logic to be executed again when `state.baz` **becomes available**. In fact, even if you write something like `{{ state.baz ? state.baz.qux : "default value" }}` in your template, it will also work. The final string displayed will reactively reflect state.baz.qux.

This can happen because `reactive` not only creates a single top level proxy object, it also recursively converts all the nested objects into reactive proxies, and this process continues to happen at runtime even for the sub objects created on the fly. Dependencies on properties of reactive objects are **continuously discovered and tracked at runtime whenever a property access attempt is made against a reactive object**. With this in mind, you can work out this expression `{{ state.baz ? state.baz.qux : "default value" }}` step by step:

1. the first time it is evaluated, the expression will read **baz** off **state** (in other words, a property access is attempted on `state` for property `baz`). Being a proxy object, **state** will remember that your expression depends on its property `baz`, even though `baz` does not exist yet. **Reactivity off `baz` is provided by the `state` object that owns the property**.
2. since `state.baz` returns `undefined`, the expression evaluates to "default value" without bothering looking at `state.baz.qux`. There is no dependency recorded on `state.baz.qux` in this round, but this is fine. *Because you cannot mutate `qux` without mutating `baz` first*.
3. somewhere in your code you assign a value to `state.baz`: `state.baz = { qux: "hello" }`. This mutation qualifies as a mutation to the `baz` property of `state`, hence your expression is scheduled for re-evaluation. Meanwhile, what gets assigned to `state.baz` is a **sub proxy** created on the fly for `{ qux: "hello" }`
4. your expression is evaluated again, this time `state.baz` is not `undefined` so the expression progresses to `state.baz.qux`. "hello" is returned, and a dependency on `qux` property is recorded off the proxy object `state.baz`. **This is what I mean by dependencies are discovered and recorded at runtime as they happen**.
5. some time later you change `state.baz.qux = "hi"`. This is a mutation to the `qux` property and hence your expression will be evaluated again.

With the above in mind, you should be able understand this as well: you can store `state.foo` in a separate variable: `const foo = state.foo`. Reactivity works off your variable `foo` just fine. `foo` points to the same thing that `state.foo` is pointing to - a reactive proxy object. The power of reactivity comes from the proxy object. By the way, `const baz = state.baz` wouldn't work the same, more on this later.

However, there are always edge cases to watch for:

1. the recursive creation of nested proxies can only happen if there is a nested object. If a given property does not exist, or it exists but it is not an object, no proxy can be created at that property. E.g. this is why reactivity does not work off the `baz` variable created by `const baz = state.baz`, nor the `bar` variable of `const bar = state.foo.bar`. To make it clear, what it means is that you can use `state.baz` and `state.foo.bar` in your template/computed/watch, but not `baz` or `bar` created above.
2. if you extract a nest proxy out to a variable, it is **detached** from its original parent. This can be made clearer with an example. The second assignment below (`state.foo = {bar: 3}`) does not destroy the reactivity of `foo`, but `state.foo` will be a new proxy object while the `foo` variable still points the to original proxy object.

```
const state = reactive({foo: {bar: 1}});
const foo = state.foo;

state.foo.bar = 2;
foo.bar === 2; // true, because foo and state.foo are the same

state.foo = {bar: 3};
foo.bar === 3; // false, foo.bar will still be 2
```

`ref` and `toRef` solve some of these edge cases.

**ref**

`ref` is pretty much the `reactive` that works also with primitives. We still cannot turn JS primitives into Proxy objects, so `ref` always wraps the provided argument `X` into an object of shape `{value: X}`. It does not matter if X is primitive or not, the "boxing" always happens. If an object is given to `ref`, `ref` internally calls `reactive` after the boxing so the result is also deeply reactive. The major difference in practice is that you need to keep in mind to call `.value` in your js code when working with ref. In your template you dont have to call `.value` because Vue automatically unwraps ref in template.

```
const count = ref(1);
const objCount = ref({count: 1});

count.value === 1; // true
objCount.value.count === 1; // true
```

**toRef**

`toRef` is meant to convert a property of a reactive object into a `ref`. You might be wondering why this is necessary since reactive object is already deeply reactive. `toRef` is here to handle the two edge cases mentioned for `reactive`. In summary, `toRef` can convert any property of a reactive object into a ref that is linked to its original parent. The property can be one that does not exist initially, or whose value is primitive.

In the same example where state is defined as `const state = reactive({foo: {bar: 1}})`:

- `const foo = toRef(state, 'foo')` will be very similar to `const foo = state.foo` but with two differences:

  1. `foo` is a `ref` so you need to do `foo.value` in js;
  2. `foo` is linked to its parent, so reassigning `state.foo = {bar: 2}` will get reflected in `foo.value`
- `const baz = toRef(state, 'baz')` now works.

**toRefs**

`toRefs` is a utility method used for destructing a reactive object and convert all its properties to ref:

```
const state = reactive({...});
return {...state}; // will not work, destruction removes reactivity 
return toRefs(state); // works
```